# Error when using predicate as comparison function

Tags: c++

I defined my `map` like this:

`std::map<Order*, OrderItems, SortOrders>`

and here's `SortOrders`:

```
class SortOrders {
        public: 
            bool operator() (const Order& x, const Order& y) const { return x.id() < y.id(); }
    };
```

Why am I getting this error?

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘const class Order’
    bool operator() (const Order& x, const Order& y) const { return x.id() < y.id(); }
                                                                          ^
```

Comment: You need the definition of `Order` to be available before implementation of `SortOrders`. Then you need implement a functor that actually compares pointers to `Order`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You map uses pointers as keys, but the comparator compares objects.

Either change the key type to `Order`, or the comparator to

```
bool operator() (const Order* x, const Order* y) const { return x->id() < y->id(); }
```

The "incomplete type" error would be because the definition of `class Order` isn't available. Make sure you're including the header that defines it.

The "control reaches end of function" warning is probably a result of that - the compiler gives up interpreting the return statement, then thinks there isn't a return statement.

Comment: a lot of errors are gone now, but I still get `invalid use of incomplete type` exactly the same on I described before. I also get this warning warning: `control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    bool operator() (const Order* x, const Order* y) const { return x->id() < y->id(); }`

Comment: @dabadaba: Sorry, I didn't notice that error. It means you haven't defined `Order` before using it; make sure you're including the header that defines it.

Comment: Look at the comment from @juanchopanza on your original question post. Should explain that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes, I included the header.

Comment: @dabadaba: And does the definition of `Order` come before that of `SortOrders`?

Comment: @MikeSeymour `SortOrders` is defined in `order-article.h` and this file includes `order.h`. But `order.h` also includes `order-article.h`. Each ones uses the other. Might this be the reason that's causing the problem? how can I fix it then?

Comment: @dabadaba: Yes, that's the problem; you can't have both files including the other. It sounds like the solution is to move `SortOrders` into `order.h`, after the definition of `Order`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I did that and it doesn't work, I am getting even more errors.

Comment: @dabadaba: So read the error to figure out why it doesn't work, and rearrange the code to make sure everything is defined where it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

Your map is keyed by `Order*`, but your predicate expects and `Order` (or actually `const Order&`). These aren't compatible types.

Either change your predicate to accept `Order*` (or `const Order*`), or change the map to store `Order` objects by value and not by pointer.

Looking at the text of the error itself - does `SortOrders` actually see the full definition of `Order`? That most likely means, are you `#include`ing the header files which defines `Order`?